# fine uploader uploadStoredFiles method

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I've run into a problem using Fine Uploader for AWS S3 when attempting to call the uploadStoredFiles() method. Everything works fine with no errors until I call this method, then I get a js error:

```
"Method uploadStoredFiles() does not exist on jQuery.fineUploader"
```

I tried using both ".fineUploader" and ".fineUploaderS3" with the same results.

```
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="sccfile">Add SCC File</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="scriptfile">Add Script File</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="notesfile">Add Notes File</div>

<div id='fineUploader'>
    <div id="submitUploads" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Submit</div>
</div>


<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fineUploader').fineUploaderS3({
        uploaderType: 'basic',
        autoUpload: false,
        extraButtons: [
            { element: $('#mediafile')  },
            { element: $('#sccfile')    },
            { element: $('#scriptfile') },
            { element: $('#notesfile')  }
        ],
        //  the remaining unrelated options omitted for brevity
    })})

    $('#submitUploads').click(function(){
        $('#fineUploader').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles()');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your code.  Fine Uploader's jQuery plug-in wrapper follows all conventions common to jQuery plug-ins.  When calling a method on a jQuery plug-in that has no arguments, simply include the method name as a parameter.  All parameters associated with the method call must follow the method name in the comma-separated list of arguments.

For example:
`$('#fineUploader').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');`

It is for this reason (and many more) that I suggest not even bothering with the jQuery plug-in wrapper. jQuery plug-in syntax is bizarre and non-intuitive, and Fine Uploader's jQuery wrapper does not provide any benefits.

For example, without the jQuery wrapper, you would call the same method like this:
`uploader.uploadStoredFiles();`